# Gnuplot scatter with xticlabels and errorbars

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to do a scatter plot with Y error bars in GNUPLOT, in which the X axis are "names", not numbers.
I'm using this code:

```
    #!/bin/sh

gnuplot -persist <<PLOT

set boxwidth 0.99 relative #ancho relativo de las barras

set border linewidth 1.5
set xlabel "xlabel" font "Verdana,18"
set xlabel offset 0,-1
#set xrange [-5:5]
set xtics font "Verdana,12"
set ylabel "ylabel" font "Verdana,18"
set ylabel offset -2,0
set yrange [-15:15]
set ytics font "Verdana,12"
set key at 4,4 font "Verdana,18"
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 7   # circle
set xtics rotate by -45 #rota ángulo

plot "file.txt" using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with yerrorbars ls 1
quit
PLOT
```

As a bash script, and then the file.txt is:

```
Peter   3.06 0.5035
Charles 4.6576 0
Luis -13.1790 0
```

Where the third column is the Y error bar. However, data appears to initiate exactly in the Origin and not as usual when histogram is used...
Any clues to "shift" or set a range on X with non-numeric values?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use autoscaling on the x-axis and just add some space to the right and left, then use `set offset`:

```
set yrange [-15:15]
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 7   # circle
set xtics rotate by -45
set offset 0.5,0.5,0,0
plot "file.txt" using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with yerrorbars ls 1 notitle
```

[image]